# Regular expressions: Ensuring b doesn't come between a and c

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Here's something I'm trying to do with regular expressions, and I can't figure out how. I have a big file, and strings `abc`, `123` and `xyz` that appear multiple times throughout the file.

I want a regular expression to match a substring of the big file that begins with `abc`, contains `123` somewhere in the middle, ends with `xyz`, **and there are no other instances of `abc` or `xyz` in the substring besides the start and the end.**

Is this possible with regular expressions?

Comment: [Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) That said, is there any particular reason you want to use regular expressions here? It's possible, but in most environments, it's more complicated than not using regexes.

Comment: Should line breaks be considered or not? The big file will be read line by line or as one big string?

Comment: Regex flavor is python 2.7, newlines should be included.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**When your left- and right-hand delimiters are single characters**, it can be easily solved with [negated character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). So, if your match is between `a` and `c` and should not contain `b` (*literally*), you may use ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW5uZ0/3))

```
a[^abc]*c
```

This is the same technique you use when you want to make sure there is a `b` in between *the closest* `a` and `c` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW5uZ0/4)):

```
a[^abc]*b[^ac]*c
```

**When your left- and right-hand delimiters are multi-character strings**, you need a **[tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)**:

```
abc(?:(?!abc|xyz|123).)*123(?:(?!abc|xyz).)*xyz
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW5uZ0/1)

To make sure it matches across lines, use `re.DOTALL` flag when compiling the regex.

Note that to achieve a better performance with such a heavy pattern, you should consider unrolling it. It can be done with negated character classes and negative lookaheads.

**Pattern details**:

- `abc` - match `abc`
- `(?:(?!abc|xyz|123).)*` - match any character that is not the starting point for a `abc`, `xyz` or `123` character sequences
- `123` - a literal string `123`
- `(?:(?!abc|xyz).)*` - any character that is not the starting point for a `abc` or `xyz` character sequences
- `xyz` - a trailing substring `xyz`

See the diagram below (if `re.S` is used, `.` will mean `AnyChar`):

[image]

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/8LZiEV):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'abc(?:(?!abc|xyz|123).)*123(?:(?!abc|xyz).)*xyz', re.DOTALL)
s = "abc 123 xyz\nabc abc 123 xyz\nabc text 123 xyz\nabc text xyz xyz"
print(p.findall(s))
// => ['abc 123 xyz', 'abc 123 xyz', 'abc text 123 xyz']
```

Comment: Can you please link the site from where you generated that state machine? I know a site exists with similar UI but can't find it though. Sorry for the irrelevant comment. I'll delete it soon :)

Comment: Why the `|123`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Well, you may get rid of that if you use a lazy quantifier in the first case: `r'abc(?:(?!abc|xyz).)*?123(?:(?!abc|xyz).)*xyz'`. It will work similarly.

Comment: Both are just optimizations, though, right? Not necessary?

Comment: That is optimization.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew which software is used to draw diagram

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew I think you meant "between a and c" in your first pharagraph. I tried to edit it but I don't want to add noise to complete 6 chacters rule.

Answer (score 3):

Using PCRE a solution would be:

This using `m` flag. If you want to check only from start and end of a line add `^` and `$` at beginning and end respectively

```
abc(?!.*(abc|xyz).*123).*123(?!.*(abc|xyz).*xyz).*xyz
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RC1zd10M7X9O7kGo)

Comment: which software is used to draw diagram

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi It is not a software, it is the [Debuggex Site](https://www.debuggex.com) there is a link in the answer

Answer (score 2):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240408/regular-expressions-ensuring-b-doesnt-come-between-a-and-c#comment62009846_37240408) by [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) is quite appropriate, and this just provides an example.  In SQL, for instance, I think it would be clearer to do:

```
where val like 'abc%123%xyz' and
      val not like 'abc%abc%' and
      val not like '%xyz%xyz'
```

I imagine something quite similar is simple to do in other environments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use lookaround.

```
/^abc(?!.*abc).*123.*(?<!xyz.*)xyz$/g
```

(I've not tested it.)