# Regular Expression to find mp3 URLs without a specific word

Tags: regex, url

I'd like to extract mp3 urls from a page source that does not have a specific word in them.

Here is the regular expression that I am using to search for mp3 urls:

```
https?:\/\/.+\.mp3
```

It works okay. Now I want to exclude those urls that have a specific word in them. So, I need urls that do not have a specific word in them.

How can I exclude a word between `http` and `.mp3`?

I will use it in Qt with C++, but as long as it works with https://regex101.com/ it is fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expressions: Ensuring b doesn't come between a and c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240408/regular-expressions-ensuring-b-doesnt-come-between-a-and-c)

Comment: @CertainPerformance - No, that is different. If you read the description, it says `contains 123 somewhere in the middle`. However, I want the expression NOT to contain a word.

Comment: It's exactly the same - see the last part of the question, `and there are no other instances of abc or xyz in the substring besides the start and the end.` - just like the top answer prevents `abc` from occurring in the middle of the match, you just need to apply the same logic to your pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "exclude those urls that *do not have* a specific word in them", you can use a positive lookahead for the word (with some number of characters before it) e.g.

```
(?=.*Sing)
```

In Javascript:

```js
const word = 'Sing';
const urls = ['http://I_like_to_sing.mp3', 'http://Another_song.mp3'];
let regex = new RegExp('https?:\/\/(?=.*' + word + ').+\.mp3', 'i');
console.log(urls.filter(v => v.match(regex)));
```

In PHP

```
$word = 'Sing';
$urls = ['http://I_like_to_sing.mp3', 'http://Another_song.mp3'];
$regex = "/https?:\/\/(?=.*$word).+\.mp3/i";
print_r(array_filter($urls, function ($v) use ($regex) { return preg_match($regex, $v); }));
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => http://I_like_to_sing.mp3 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/MpRbO)

**Update**

To exclude those URLs that *do* have a specific word in them, you can use a negative lookahead instead e.g.

```
(?![^.]*Sing)
```

We use `[^.]` to ensure the word occurs *before* the `.mp3` part. Here's a PHP demo:

```
$word = 'Song';
$string = "some words http://I_like_to_sing.mp3 and then some other words http://Another_song.mp3 and some words at the end...";
$regex = "/(https?:\/\/(?![^.]*$word).+?\.mp3)/i";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => http://I_like_to_sing.mp3
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/dS9LF)

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my question, I fixed it.

Comment: @NESHOM you shouldn't mark this accepted, it doesn't answer your actual question. I had been meaning to revisit the question though and I've made an edit which I think will solve your problem.

Comment: You ate right. It did help a bit, but not answered directly. So, please post your updated answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be a useful answer.

This a regular expression with use case on **python3**. So if you want to exclude a "word" between **http** & **.mp3** you can do this.

```
import re

ref = "http://www.some_undesired_text_018/m102/1-225x338.mp3"

_del = re.findall(r'https?(.+)\.mp3', ref)[0]

out = ref.replace(_del, "")

#_del will contain the undesired word
```

Comment: I am not using python.

Answer (score 0):

A minor edit to Nick's answer. You can exclude the word by negating the value returned from the match in the filter function like so:

```
urls.filter(v => !v.match(regex));
```

This works and is much easier than the other one solution further down, which gives an unexpected result.

```js
const word = 'Sing';
const urls = ['http://I_like_to_sing.mp3', 'http://Another_song.mp3'];
let regex = new RegExp('https?:\/\/(?=.*' + word + ').+\.mp3', 'i');
console.log(urls.filter(v => !v.match(regex)));
```