# How to match a range of string that doesn't contain an specific word using only regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string like this.

```
var str = "[cat dog] [dog cow] [cow cat] [cat tiger] [tiger lion] [monkey dog]";
```

I want to match the pair of animals that doesn't contain a specific one.
For example I want to select all pair of animals that doesn't contain dog.
So the output should be

```
[cow cat]
[cat tiger]
[tiger lion]
```

Is it possible to match using Regular Expression using `str.match()` method?

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240408/regular-expressions-ensuring-b-doesnt-come-between-a-and-c

Comment: Sorry @CertainPerformance, that question is different.

Comment: No, it's the same, just match `[`, lazy-anything which doesn't contain `dog` (using linked method), then match `]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```js
var regex = /\[(?!dog)([a-z]+) (?!dog)([a-z]+)\]/gi;
var string = "[cat dog] [dog cow] [cow cat] [cat tiger] [tiger lion] [monkey dog]";
console.log(string.match(regex));
```

The above regex matches only two animals in each pair of brackets - this one matches one or more:

```js
var regex = /\[((?!dog)([a-z]+) ?){2,}\]/gi;
var string = "[cat dog] [dog cow] [cow cat] [cat tiger] [tiger lion] [monkey dog] [one animal two animal three animal]";
console.log(string.match(regex));
```