# Regex match line with string AND without another string

Tags: regex

There are tons of great answers on SO how to match a line that does not contain a line, or match until a string of characters.

I am trying to tweak these into a regex that matches lines with a specific word AND lacking a certain word.

An example line that I want to find:

```
var status = await _client.Get<Status>();
```

An example line that I don't want to find:

```
await _client.GetStream().WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Thus, every line that starts with 'await' and does not specify 'ConfigureAwait' should be matched.

I've tried all kind of things, e.g. :

```
regex: await.*(?!Configure)
```

But whenever I use something like .* in the regex, it matches everything (including the `ConfigureAwait` part).

So how do I tell the regex parser to 'match anything BUT <...>'

Comment: move the `.*` into the negative lookahead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expressions: Ensuring b doesn't come between a and c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240408/regular-expressions-ensuring-b-doesnt-come-between-a-and-c)

Comment: @Nick that was spot on thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `(?=^.*await)(?!^.+ConfigureAwait).+`

Explanation:

`(?=^.*await)` - positive lookahead: assert what is following is: `^` beginning of a line, followed by one or more of any characters due to `.+` and a word `await`, concisely: assert that there is `await` in a line

`(?!^.+ConfigureAwait)` - negative lookahead: similairly to above, but negated :) assert that following line doesn't contain `ConfigureAwait`

`.+` - match one ore more of any character (except new line)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM79p4/2)