# How do I match strings not containing strings in VSCode's search and replace?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

How do I match strings not containing strings in VSCode's search and replace?

Everything I've found googling (even on here) is either how to do it in via programming,

how to match strings not containing individual characters,

or not compatible with VSCode's regex processing.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240408/regular-expressions-ensuring-b-doesnt-come-between-a-and-c) doesn't answer my question.

That question is specifically via programming.

Which I already stated last time I asked was **not** relevant/applicable, and why that method isn't relevant/applicable.

I shouldn't have to repost with this edit, as the original already stated why that question doesn't help.

But I need to do it to match strings not containing the string, and not the individual characters in it.

I also need said string to in and of its self match using regex.

My appoligies.

I need to match everything but the strings matched by this.

recipes.add(Shaped|Shapeless)\((.+), \[((<(.+)>|null)|(<(.+)>|null), (<(.+)>|null)|(<(.+)>|null), (<(.+)>|null), (<(.+)>|null)|(<(.+)>|null), (<(.+)>|null), (<(.+)>|null), (<(.+)>|null))\]\);

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit too broad and without a concrete example, but basically a thing you can do to avoid a substring is:

```
START(?:(?!WHATIWANTTOAVOID).)*END
```

or to get the shortest match:

```
START(?:(?!WHATIWANTTOAVOID).)*?END
```

The idea is that for each position between START and END, WHATIWANTTOAVOID is tested using a negative lookahead *(not followed by)*.

A lookahead is a zero-width assertion that doesn't consume characters, so in the example the lookahead and `.` (the dot) are tested at the same positions in the subject string.

Comment: my appologies, corrected.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the most complete answer to "How to invert regex matching string in vscode". I'm glad I did check beneath the what google search results shoved up to my face that did not even work. You saved my life!!!