# Is there a way to find the rows which does not contain a specific text in Visual stuido code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to know if there is a way to find out the rows which do not contain a specific text in Visual studio code. I have around 60000 rows and It is really difficult to find the rows without a specific text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63143965/9938317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex find with

```
^(?!.*MyText).*
```

At the start of a line, test if the string `MyText` is not anywhere on the line. And then select the whole line.

If you want to select all lines that contain a certain text use

```
^(?=.*MyText).*
```