# What regular expression (PCRE) will find two occurrences of a specific word that do not contain a specific word between them?

Tags: regex, pcre

I need help coming up with a PCRE regular expression that will find two occurrences of a word without a certain word between them in a multiline file.

The first example below should be matched because "foo" occurs twice without the word "bar" between them, while the second example should not be matched because "foo" occurs twice with the word "bar" between them.

Matching Example:

**foo**
jumped
over
the
lazy
**foo**

Nonmatching Example:

**foo**
jumped
over
the
**bar**
**foo**

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [Regular expressions: Ensuring b doesn't come between a and c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240408)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question may have been asked before, though perhaps not exactly in the same way.  One approach here is to use a tempered dot when matching between occurrences of `foo`, to ensure that we don't cross over `bar` along the way.  Try running the following regex with dot all mode enabled:

```
\bfoo\b((?!\bbar\b).)*?\bfoo\b
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used:

```
\bfoo\b           match an initial "foo"
((?!\bbar\b).)*?  match any content, including across newlines, provided
                  that we do not pass "bar" along the way
\bfoo\b           match a final "foo"
```

If you don't have dot all mode available, you may simulate it using a similar pattern:

```
\bfoo\b((?!\bbar\b)[\s\S])*?\bfoo\b
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I found a similar working expression: "foo(?:(?!bar).)*?foo" but the word boundary assertion is a good addition.

Comment: @dave_erie The main difference between what you pasted above and my answer is that your version is not using word boundaries.  There could be sample data for which your pattern might have a false positive.