# Match multiple same occurence after one specific character chain REGEX

Tags: php, regex

Thanks to anyone that will try to help me.
I struggle into making a regex that can do this case :
*I want every match of "Heure Pleine Saison Basse" that occur after the first occurence of "Acheminement conso".*

Using the raw text below, i want to match "Heure Pleine Saison Basse" 3  5 6 7 and not 1 & 2.
**Do not use the number inside characted recognition, it is just here to help you uderstand which chain i want to match**

This example regex only match the last occurrence :

```
Acheminement[\s\S]*(Heure Pleine Saison Basse)
```

Here is a great raw text example :

```
Electricité n° de\n
compteur ancien\n
index nouvel\n
index conso\n
kWh/Qté prix unitaire\n
HT en euros montant HT\n
en euros taux de\n
TVA\n
Contribution cee du 14/07/22 au 13/08/22 143020,00495 70,7920,0%\n
Evolutions arenh du 14/07/22 au 13/08/22 14302-0,03149 -450,3720,0%\n
Consommation  du 14/07/22 au 13/08/22 154\n
Heure Pleine Saison Basse 1
Heure Pleine Saison Basse 2
Heure Creuse Saison Basse 2
Acheminement conso\n
kWh/Qté prix unitaire\n
HT en euros montant HT\n
en euros taux de\n
TVA\n
Composante de comptage du 1
Composante de comptage du 2
Composante de soutirage du 1
Composante de soutirage du 2
Composante de gestion 1
Composante de gestion 2
Consommation du 14/07/22 au 31/07/22 Heure Pleine Saison Basse 56200,02000 112,4020,0%\n
Heure Creuse Saison Basse 26840,01700 45,6320,0%\n
Consommation du 01/08/22 au 13/08/22\n
Heure Pleine Saison Basse 3
Heure Creuse Saison Basse 4
Heure Pleine Saison Basse 5
Heure Pleine Saison Basse 6
Heure Pleine Saison Basse 7
Services et prestations techniques conso\n
kWh/Qté prix unitaire\n
HT en euros montant HT\n
en euros taux de\n
TVA\n
Espace Client Gratuit\n
Taxes et Contributions conso\n
```

Comment: Like `/(?:\G(?!\A)|Acheminement conso)[\s\S]*?\KHeure Pleine Saison Basse/u`? See https://regex101.com/r/GNx87r/1

Comment: This is working, you are amazing, you can post it as an answer so i can flag it as accepted answer

Comment: It would be incredible if you take the time to explain it a bit so i can better understand what techinique you used :)

Comment: This regex is amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
'/(?:\G(?!\A)|Acheminement conso)[\s\S]*?\KHeure Pleine Saison Basse/u'
'/(?:\G(?!\A)|Acheminement conso).*?\KHeure Pleine Saison Basse/su'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GNx87r/2). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|Acheminement conso)`  - either `Acheminement conso` or the end of the previous match (`\G(?!\A)` is matching what [`\G` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14897949/3832970) matches except the position at the start of string that is "cancelled" with the `(?!\A)` negative lookahead)
- `[\s\S]*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\K` - [omit the text](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) matched so far
- `Heure Pleine Saison Basse` - a fixed string.

The `u` flag is necessary when you have to deal with Unicode strings.
The `s` flag is useful to make `.` match any characters including line breaks.

Comment: If i may. I have a similar usecase with an occurence at the end :
If i describe it : Match all "pointe" between "Obligation Capacité" and "Acheminement conso"  
 
Here the first 2 match are correct, and the third one is not good and could be prevent by the occurrence of "Acheminement conso"

https://regex101.com/r/SOsd3y/1

Comment: Sorry if i ask for more example, but i really need to be better at regex, and example like this help me learn a lot

Comment: @ThomasL I believe you need something like https://regex101.com/r/SOsd3y/2

Comment: It work, amazing ! but this also work https://regex101.com/r/zgeKmK/1
So why did you add this group (?:(?!Obligation Capacité)[\s\S]) ?
I ask to understand your mindset better, not because i think its wrong :)

Comment: @ThomasL The tempered greedy token is used to make sure the match only occurs between the closest `A` and any rightmost `B`. You may disregard that restriction.  See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37240408/3832970) to understand this.