# Regex: negative look-ahead with repeated HTML tag (nested tables)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, nested-table

I want to match the range between an HTML opening tag `<table` and a closing tag `</table>` as long as there is not any opening tag `<table` inbetween. Example:

```html
<html><body><title>1</title><br><table width=300 height=35 border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td align=center width=50><table width=300 border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>A</td></tr></table><tr><td><br>B</td></tr></table>
    <br><td><tr></td></tr><table width=300 height=35 border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td align=center width=50><table width=300 border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>C</td></tr></table><tr><td><br>D</td></tr></table>
    <td><tr></td></tr><br><table width=300 height=35 border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td align=center width=50><table width=300 border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>E</td></tr></table><tr><td><br>F</td></tr></table>
```

Each `<table` which is eventually followed by another `<table` before reaching `</table` should be disregarded. Consequently, the first match should be:

```html
<table width=300 border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>A</td></tr></table>
```

The match should not be:

```html
<table width=300 height=35 border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td align=center width=50><table width=300 border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>A</td></tr></table>
```

...and so on.

Regex tried: `(<table(?!<table)(.+?)</table>)`

Comment: Please edit your question and include regex you used directly within question. Question needs to be standalone and should not require visiting outside links.

Comment: How about this, `<table[^>]*>.*?<\/table>`, https://regex101.com/r/q8BGCl/1, no need for lookarounds

Comment: @Buttered_Toast nice, but top-level tables are still matched.

Comment: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240408/regular-expressions-ensuring-b-doesnt-come-between-a-and-c

Comment: Why was this Q tagged [Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi)? You didn't even mention it, let alone making it important.