# Find xml Element containing specific subelement

Tags: regex, xml

What is a correct Regex (PCRE2) to select only `<Item>...</Item>` Elements containing a `<B>255</B>` Element?

I've tried the following Regex (and a ton of others) but the problem is always, that it's either not matching or matching too many Item elements, if it doesn't find the `<B>255</B>` Element

```
<Item(.|\n)*?<B>255<\/B>(.|\n)*?<\/Item>
```

I've also tried negative and positve lookahead but couldn't bring it to work.

Sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Favourites>
  <Buttons>
    <Item KID="1">
      <ButtonColor>
        <R>255</R>
        <G>255</G>
        <B>255</B>
      </ButtonColor>
    </Item>
    <Item KID="2">
    </Item>
    <Item KID="3">
      <ButtonColor>
        <R>239</R>
        <G>235</G>
        <B>233</B>
      </ButtonColor>
    </Item>
    <Item KID="7">
      <ButtonColor>
        <R>255</R>
        <G>255</G>
        <B>255</B>
      </ButtonColor>
    </Item>
```

What it matches:

```
<Item KID="1">
      <ButtonColor>
        <R>255</R>
        <G>255</G>
        <B>255</B>
      </ButtonColor>
    </Item>
```

and also:

```
<Item KID="2">
    </Item>
    <Item KID="3">
      <ButtonColor>
        <R>239</R>
        <G>235</G>
        <B>233</B>
      </ButtonColor>
    </Item>
    <Item KID="7">
      <ButtonColor>
        <R>255</R>
        <G>255</G>
        <B>255</B>
      </ButtonColor>
    </Item>
```

What I want to match:

```
<Item KID="1">
      <ButtonColor>
        <R>255</R>
        <G>255</G>
        <B>255</B>
      </ButtonColor>
    </Item>
```

and also:

```
<Item KID="7">
      <ButtonColor>
        <R>255</R>
        <G>255</G>
        <B>255</B>
      </ButtonColor>
    </Item>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Best!

Answer derived from here:
[Regular expressions: Ensuring b doesn't come between a and c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240408/regular-expressions-ensuring-b-doesnt-come-between-a-and-c)

```
<Item(?:(?!<Item|<\/Item>|<B>255<\/B>).)*<B>255<\/B>(?:(?!<Item|<\/Item>).)*<\/Item>
```

Comment: Yes, and keep in mind that `.` does not always match newlines, so check out [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159118/3832970)

Comment: Obligatory link: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: Thank you both. I adapted my code and replaced the . with (.|\n)